# A vetriloquist with a living doll attached to his hand

Tags: story-identification, tv

I remember an episode from a series (maybe "Ray Bradbury's theater") in which a man is a retired ventriloquist who has his forearm covered with bandages... A man is investigating something and discovers that beneath the bandages is the ventriloquist's Siamese brother, a psycho murderer.

The ventriloquist eventually chops his "brother-hand" but this little human kills him. The episode ends with the man performing a ventriloquist show with the little fiend.

Could any one help me identify the series and the name of the episode?

Comment: Based on the question title, I was going to make a Senor Wences joke.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say this is a *Tales from the Crypt* episode "[The Ventriloquist's Dummy](https://tftc.fandom.com/wiki/The_Ventriloquist%27s_Dummy)". The Ventriloquist with the attached twin/substitute dummy was played by Don Rickles, Bobcat Goldthawait played the aspiring Ventriloquist who discovers the two and ends up with the severed "Siamese twin" attached to his wrist at the end.